# WooCommerce Categories wise Page Design/Template

Tags: php, woocommerce

My client have 3 different categories Furniture / Cloths/ Mobile.

What we are looking for is 3 different template style for each categories like if furniture we want to change theme to suit furniture likewise for other categories.

Is there a way to do it. like in magento, is there any plugin

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the plugin but a simple solution is here.

In `header.php` use these conditions.

```
if(is_product_category("furniture"))
{

  stylesheets for category  furniture

}

elseif((is_product_category("something"))
{

   stylesheets for category something else

}

else
{
default styling files
}
```

that's it.